# Как избежать конфликта стилей CSS расширения Google Chrome и CSS страниц?

Tags: css, chrome-extension

Имеем расширение Google Chrome в котором используется Bootstrap и скрипт для создания модальных окон arctic-modals. В итоге на некоторых сайтах неверно отображаются формы расширения. Полагаю что это из-за конфликта CSS стилей, которые нужно инжектить на страницу, чтобы формы выводились через content.js. Есть ли способ избежать этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так: скомпилируйте ваши css-файлы, например, с помощью **less** с уникальным префиксом:

**`my_chrome_app.less`**:

```
.my-chrome-app {
  @import (less) url("bootstrap.css");
}
```

В результате получится файл, в котором все классы бутстрэпа обёрнуты в родителя `.my_chrome_app`:

**`my_chrome_app.css`**:

```
...
.my_chrome_app .lead {
  font-size: 21px;
}
...
```

А в генерируемых формах весь код нужно обернуть в нужный div.

```
<div class="my-chrome-app">
  <div class="lead">Текст с нашими стилями bootstrap</div>
</div>
```

Тогда стили из ваших css-файлов будут применяться только к вашим формам. Однако, стили страниц всё равно будут влиять на отображение ваших форм, хотя и будут иметь более низкий приоритет.

Про **less**: [на английском](http://lesscss.org/), [на русском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_%28%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%29).

Comment: Не пользовался less ни разу. Не дадите ссылку где почитать, чтоб сделать так как вы советуете?

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! :) 

Добавил начальные ссылки для изучения less. Не забудьте отметить вопрос как решение и плюсануть, если он вам помог.